# How to get a 0 instead of No result using parent child table and group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `budgets_planned` and `budgets_details`, where `budgets_planned` is the parent table and `budget_details` is the child table.  I want to be able to show in a column the sum of the budget_detail line items that have been approved.  I did get that to work, however, when a new budget is made and there are no child rows in `budget_details`, instead of showing a 0 in that column, the entire row does not show up.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT  p.idx,
p.asset_type,
p.asset_name,
p.bms_id,
p.ra_code,
p.work_package,
COALESCE(SUM(a.cost),0) as 'Approved Budget ($)'
FROM budgets_planned as p
LEFT JOIN budgets_details as a
ON p.idx = a.parentAssetIdx
WHERE a.deleted is NULL AND a.approval = 1
GROUP BY p.idx, p.asset_type, p.asset_name, p.bms_id, p.ra_code, p.work_package
```

I tried using a `COALESCE` but to no avail.  How can I make my `Approved Budget ($)` column show a 0 if there are no rows in `budgets_details` instead of having SQL nix the entire row all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a row for a `budgets_planned` even if there are no rows in `budgets_details`, just include the filtering condition as part of the `JOIN` predicate:

```
SELECT  p.idx,
p.asset_type,
p.asset_name,
p.bms_id,
p.ra_code,
p.work_package,
COALESCE(SUM(a.cost),0) as 'Approved Budget ($)'
FROM budgets_planned as p
LEFT JOIN budgets_details as a
       ON p.idx = a.parentAssetIdx
      AND a.deleted is NULL AND a.approval = 1
GROUP BY p.idx, p.asset_type, p.asset_name, p.bms_id, p.ra_code, p.work_package
```

Comment: Ok that does work so thank you, but why does it work whereas mine did not?

Comment: It behaves differently when there are no rows in the right table for a left join. If you place a predicate in the `JOIN` clause (the solution) it will keep rows from the left table, while including nulls in the right table. A `WHERE` clause will remove both sides (whole row).